# Show that if $\lim a_n = L$ and $a_n > a$ for all $n$, then $L \geq a$.

Tags: limits, inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing

Proof:

We know that $\lim a_n = L$ and $a_n > a$ for all $n$.

Apply the limit to both sides:
$\lim a_n > \lim a \Longrightarrow L > a$.

Thus,

$\lim a_n = L$ and $a_n > a$ implies that $L \geq a$. QED.

Thoughts?

Comment: Be careful when taking limits of an inequality.this cannot be done unless you know the limits exist for the terms in both sides.however, here this is fine since you are given that a is a constant and limit of a-n exists.

Comment: This kind of feels like cheating in a way, unless you have a result which says that limits preserve inequalities. BTW, if $a_n>b_n$ and have limits $L,M$ respectively, then taking limits of both sides gives at best $L\geq M$, not necessarily $>$.

Comment: good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write $\lim a_n > \lim a$, it should be $\lim a_n \ge \lim a$, which gives $L \ge a$, as desired. If you didn't have the theorem at hand, you can argue by contraposition. Suppose $L < a$. Set $\epsilon = (a - L)/2$. Then $\epsilon > 0$, so since $\lim a_n = L$, there exists an $N$ such that $a_N < L + \epsilon$, i.e., $a_N < (a + L)/2$. Since $L < a$, $(a + L)/2 < a$. Hence $a_N < a$.

Comment: How did you get  ϵ=(a−L)/2. ?

Comment: I defined $\epsilon$ to be $(a - L)/2$.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you want to set epsilon equal to that?

Comment: Think of it this way. Since $\lim a_n = L$, given $\epsilon > 0$, $a_n < L + \epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$. To get a contradiction, I just need one $N$ such that $a_N < a$. To do this, I pick an $\epsilon$ such that $L + \epsilon < a$. One such choice is $(a - L)/2$.

Comment: If you're arguing by contradiction then wouldn't you have to show that a_n > a ==> L < a is false, thus a_n > a ==> L >= a?

Comment: No, but since I really argued by the contrapositive, I'll make a slight edit to indicate that.